# how to handle conflict in git in a file that was deleted upstream

Tags: git

we have a `development` branch and a `release` branch. We had to hotfix a feature in release and the file was subsequently deleted in development and the feature was effectively removed (ie we don't care about this hotfix anymore).

Now when we merge development into release we get the following error:

```
    Removing app/views/ad_sources/subforms/_ad_source_reporting_field.html.erbRemoving app/views/a
29-Aug-2018 23:35:14    CONFLICT (modify/delete): app/views/ad_sources/subforms/_ad_source_attribute_field.html.erb deleted in development and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of app/views/ad_sources/subforms/_ad_source_attribute_field.html.erb left in tree.
```

What is the best way to fix this? Perhaps just recreating an empty file in the development branch?

Comment: Note: that's not an *error*, that's an informational message. Git is telling you that it is not smart enough to do the merge on its own, and it needs your help to finish the merge. There should be a message category of "not quite an error, but not success either, and not exactly a warning"....